# Custom fetch to mock fetch api to read data from filesystem instead of http

Tags: javascript, filesystems, fetch-api

In my project there is a function `someFunction` which use [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) api to read file from http server so its slow.

I want to repalce this `someFunction` by my `mock_someFunction` which will read file from filesystem. Reading from file system would be faster then http call.

```js
// this use http call to fetch file, this is slow
function someFunction(fileName) {
    let url = `https://${HOST}/${fileName}`
    let e = fetch(url).then(function (response) {
        // response is instance of Response
        return response.arrayBuffer();
    });
    return e;
}

// this fetch file from file system, this would be fast
function mock_someFunction(fileName) {
    // we already have this file on file system so lets not use fetch api

    let e = localFetch(fileName).then(function (response) {
        // response should be instance of Response
        return response.arrayBuffer();
    })
    return e;
}

// implement this
function localFetch(fileName) {
    // read file
    var myBlob = new Blob();
    var init = { "status" : 200 , "statusText" : "SuperSmashingGreat!" };
    var myResponse = new Response(myBlob,init);
    // return reposnce promise
}
```

What should be way to create `mock_someFunction` function to make it replaceable by `someFunction`?